# Node.js application on localhost crashes

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

Background:

I have a node.js + Express + MySQL application. For development and testing I run it on my localhost and I have also deployed it on heroku which is the production side.

Problem:

Whenever I run the app on my localhost and as soon as I hit login button in the login form it crashes. Specifically, it gives the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined

This problem is related to the mysql node module I am using to connect to my database where the code looks like:

```
connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err) {
            winston.log('debug', '------------------------------------ Error: ' + err);
            callback(err, null);
        }
        connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows){
            if (err) {
                winston.log('debug', '------------------------------------ Error: ' + err);
                callback(err, null);
            }
            connection.release();
            callback(null, rows);
        });
    });
```

Clearly, the connection param is undefined and hence the error.

But before we come to the conclusion that it is my code that is the issue, the application also runs smoothly sometimes. It runs smoothly on Heroku prod site and guess what if I change my wifi connection from my home wifi to my portable wifi hotspot it never crashes.

So if I run my server on my home wifi 10 times, it will fail 8 and run smoothly 2 times. So everytime I have to work on this project I have to reconnect my laptop to my portable wifi hotspot (which is very expensive).

I tried changing the port in the code from 8000 to 3434 or 5000 but it did not help. I am really frustrated as I cannot even test my app on locahost due to my home connection. I have 4 mbps download speed which should be enough for a application like this. Also other sites like YouTube, Facebook load properly (not to mention this same application when I run it on heroku).

Is there any solution for this problem? Is it my code thats failing to connect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `return;` right after `callback(err, null);` immediately inside your `getConnection()` callback. That will prevent execution from continuing in case of an error.

You don't want to add something similar for your `query()` callback because it is important that you release the connection back to the pool no matter what.

Comment: Just modified the code as per your suggestion but the server still crashes. This time however it did log me in, then redirected to the next page and then crashed there (giving the same error)

Comment: It crashed on the *same line* or in a different place?